# ​How can I write JSON schema validation for JMeter run in TeamCity

Tags: jmeter

I'm working on **regression API testing automation using JMeter**. 
I'm searching for some basic organic solution to validate JSON schema using build-in JMeter tools. 
CI is built with **Team City** so a basic solution will be faster.

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box JMeter doesn't provide JSON Schema validation functionality, however you can use a 3rd-party library like [JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema) to add this to JMeter

1. Get the latest version of [org.everit.json.schema.jar](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema/releases)
2. Get the appropriate version of [JSON in Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json)
3. Get the appropriate version of [Handy URI Templates](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.damnhandy/handy-uri-templates)
4. Drop 3 above .jar files to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation (or whatever place in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath))
5. Add [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) which returns the JSON which you need to check against the schema (or according to the [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide))
6. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def schemaPath = '/path/to/your/schema.json'
   def rawSchema = new org.json.JSONObject(new org.json.JSONTokener(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(schemaPath), 'UTF-8')))
   def schema = org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader.load(rawSchema)
   schema.validate(new JSONObject(prev.getResponseDataAsString()))
   ```
7. That's it, if schema validation fails the affected Sampler(s) will be marked as failed

   [image]

Comment: OK, I will check the solution and give feedback. Thanks

Comment: @Dmitri T thanks for providing solution. I tried it and it is working fine. Just one thing in 4th line of script changeJSONObject to  org.json.JSONObject.

Comment: It is also possible to define a variable in params ex. _/home/myuser/myschema.json_ and access it via `def schemaPath = args[0]`. Or, even better, define a user parameter  and use it (and re-usit) in parameter field, somthing like: `${SCHEMA_PATH}/myschema.json`. Thank you Dmitri