# How to iterate through the contents of a Json object

Tags: jmeter, json-schema-validator

On the JSR223 assertion in Jmeter, I need to validate only the inner part of the JSON returned.

I followed this thread to get an idea on the validation. 
[​How can I write JSON schema validation for JMeter run in TeamCity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575805/how-can-i-write-json-schema-validation-for-jmeter-run-in-teamcity)

Basically my Jmeter sampler returns the json as follows.  On my schema, the validation should be for items, service and requestId.  No validation should be performed for "payload".

```
{
   "payload": [
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "code": "487482378",
          "description": "Alpha Co",
          "valid": true
        },
        {
          "code": "92901128365",
          "description": "Beta Co",
          "valid": true
        }
     ],
     "service": "entities",
     "requestId": "d190219"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my current code in the js223 sampler:

```
var schemaPath = '/path/entities-schema.json'
var rawSchema = new org.json.JSONObject(new org.json.JSONTokener(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(new java.io.File(schemaPath), 'UTF-8')))
var schema = org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader.load(rawSchema)
schema.validate(new org.json.JSONObject(prev.getResponseDataAsString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the "unwanted" part of the response using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) like:

```
def before = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
log.info('Before: ' + before)
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(before)
def after = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(response.payload.items).toPrettyString()
log.info('After: ' + after)
prev.setResponseData(after, 'UTF-8')
```

[image]

Once done you can use your JSON Schema validation approach against the new content without elements you don't need.

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri @DmitriT for such a fast response.  Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using javascript on my JSR223 assertion.  Also The following is how I need the json.  I need to pass on the below json to my schema validator.  Thanks again.

Comment: Here is the structure of json I need:      {
      "items": [
        {
          "code": "487482378",
          "description": "Alpha Co",
          "valid": true
        },
        {
          "code": "92901128365",
          "description": "Beta Co",
          "valid": true
        }
     ],
     "service": "entities",
     "requestId": "d190219"
    }